# WPF double click change row background color

Tags: wpf, colors, background, double-click

I Write in the code that if I selected row, that row background color change. But I have problem  if I double click on the row , the background change color again. It is not matter how many click I make, I have to get the same background color. Maybe someone know how to do it?

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="lbPersonList" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AlternationCount="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              GridLinesVisibility="None" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" 
              HeadersVisibility="Column" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" MouseDoubleClick="lbPersonList_MouseDoubleClick_1">
```

.cs:

```
 private void lbPersonList_MouseDoubleClick_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement originalSender = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
        if (originalSender != null)
        {
            var row = originalSender.ParentOfType<GridViewRow>();
            if (row != null)
            {
                row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also I got error for missing Namespace for ParentOfType(). I try us Sytem.Web.UI.WebControls, but it showing it does not exist

Comment: Please show what you've tried!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use click events. You can change background color in style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
      </Trigger>
    <Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```